# Elasticsearch API Gem Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Could not find elasticsearch-api-1.0.15 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

I installed
elasticsearch-api

ubuntu@ip-172-31-45-63:/var/www/eyehawk.io$ gem list | grep elasticsearch

elasticsearch (1.0.15)

elasticsearch-api (1.0.15)

elasticsearch-model (0.1.8)

elasticsearch-rails (0.1.8)

elasticsearch-transport (1.0.15)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the template that the gem offers. However, I can't find how to set the config to connect to amazon. The docs are lacking.